# 'uiautomator2' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: appium

I tried to open uiautomator2 from command prompt , it is showing 'uiautomator2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: better you explain the question in the correct format. what were you trying to achieve? what is your piece of code and ADB logs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.